# How to use css to add multiple styles for a paragraph

Tags: html, css

How to use css to add multiple styles for a paragraph

For Ex: in my below css code,

```
p {
    text-align: justify
}
p {
    font-size: xx-small 
}

p {
    color: aqua
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    text-align: right, 
}
li {
    text-align: center
}
```

Now as you can see i have for Paragraph the following styles kept

1. Justify
2. Small
3. Aqua Color

How can i combine all of them into the same tag rather than having it distributed in three sections

Thank you,

Comment: p{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: xx-small;
  color: aqua;
}

Comment: You mean automtically? OR what the result should look like?

Comment: Really, this not ment as an insult, but if this is the level of question you're asking about css, I recommend you do at least some research into CSS, as this is probally one of the first things you encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the semicolon `;` that is missing in your code. Normally a CSS rule ends with a semicolon. Only after the last rule before a closing curly brace (`}`) you can omit the semicolon. After that you can remove the `}` and `p {` that are *extra*.

Answer (score 3):

Just add them all in to the same declaration, like so

```
p { 
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: xx-small;
    color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly you can write your styles like this ( see snippet below )

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: aqua;
  font-size: xx-small
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: xx-small;
    color: aqua;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Geetesh. The answer you've given has already been given and that answer has a bit of explanation also. At SO we dont recommend posting "just code"  answers, but with at least a basic form of explanation. Also, if an answer already exists (as was the case before you posted), it's better not to post, unless you have actual new/extra value to add :)

Comment: As you have the same answer as Darren, you likely agree with his answer. That is when you upvote some else's answer :)